# how to read lines in python and then assign each line to a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code that will take a file see those letters then take them and make them in to other letters. hear is my code.

```
def decode():
    dd=input("would you like to type the message or read a file that has the message?:")
    if dd in['read']:
        e=open("file.txt", 'r')
        for i in range(7):
            ff=e.read()
            if ff in['wen']:
                print("new")
             ...
        e.close()
decode()
```

the output is

```
would you like to type the message or read a file that has the message?: read

>>>
```

ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything to do this yet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you show us, what is in you "file.txt"? Have you made sure that it is not empty and in the right place?

Comment: Maybe review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again... In particular, how does the output you're getting differ from what you expected? (And as wuerfelfreak pointed out, without an example of your text file, this is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).)

Comment: what I am trying to get is a string of letters like "hello world"

Comment: in my file.txt it says "wen (new line)i(new line)s...

Comment: I have done a lot including readlines() but what what is for it to get one line at a time, then based on that letter it will print a different letter

Comment: it only works if i have on line in my file.  but  if I have more than one letter or phrase that I have defined in an if statement it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of lines with `readlines()`:

```py
e = open("file.txt", 'r')
lines = e.readlines()
e.close()
```

You can also iterate through the lines of a file with a for loop:

```
e = open("file.txt", 'r')
for line in e:
     #your code here
e.close()
```